# OpenCV Region of Interest (ROI)

Tags: c++, opencv, roi

i am trying to make a code such that when roi is created when a face or faces is/are detected through a webcam, and then an image of each cropped area size face is saved to a filepath with the names being 01.jpg, 02.jpg, etc. Can anyone help me?

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);


string face_cascade_name = "C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
int filenumber; // Number of file to be saved
string filename;


int main(void)
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);

    if (!capture.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    // Load the cascade
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
    {
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return (-1);
    };

    // Read the video stream
    Mat frame;

    for (;;)
    {
        capture >> frame;

        // Apply the classifier to the frame
        if (!frame.empty())
        {
            detectAndDisplay(frame);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }

        int c = waitKey(10);

        if (27 == char(c))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function detectAndDisplay
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat crop;
    Mat res;
    Mat gray;
    string text;
    stringstream sstm;

    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    // Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    // Set Region of Interest
    cv::Rect roi_b;
    cv::Rect roi_c;

    size_t ic = 0; // ic is index of current element
    int ac = 0; // ac is area of current element

    size_t ib = 0; // ib is index of biggest element
    int ab = 0; // ab is area of biggest element

    for (ic = 0; ic < faces.size(); ic++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)

    {
        roi_c.x = faces[ic].x;
        roi_c.y = faces[ic].y;
        roi_c.width = (faces[ic].width);
        roi_c.height = (faces[ic].height);

        ac = roi_c.width * roi_c.height; // Get the area of current element (detected face)

        roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
        roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
        roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
        roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);


        crop = frame(roi_b);
        resize(crop, res, Size(128, 128), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images
        cvtColor(crop, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert cropped image to Grayscale

        // Form a filename
        filename = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Faces\\face.jpg";
        stringstream ssfn;
        ssfn << filenumber << ".jpg";
        filename = ssfn.str();
        filenumber++;


        Point pt1(faces[ic].x, faces[ic].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((faces[ic].x + faces[ic].height), (faces[ic].y + faces[ic].width));
        rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }


    // Show image
    sstm << "Crop area size: " << roi_b.width << "x" << roi_b.height << " Filename: " << filename;
    text = sstm.str();


    if (!crop.empty())
    {
        imshow("detected", crop);
    }
    else
        destroyWindow("detected");

    imwrite(filename, gray);
}
```

Comment: behind your `filenumber++` just add `cv::imwrite(filename, res):` this should write the images to your working directory. If you want to write to `C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Faces\\` change to `ssfn << filename.c_str() << filenumber << ".jpg";`

Comment: looks similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972857/saving-images-of-detected-faces-in-opencv